# ReactJS render a multilevel json structure, unable to show second level data

Tags: reactjs

I tried    `{user.address.street}`

> Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

[image]

```
const UserItem = (user, index) => (
  <div key={index} className="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
    <div className="accordion-header js-accordion-header">{(index+1)} . {user.name}
              </div>
    <div className="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
      <div className="accordion-body__contents">
        {JSON.stringify(user.address.street)}}  
               <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
                Click me
               </a>
      </div>
      <div className="accordion js-accordion">
        <div className="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
          <div className="accordion-header js-accordion-header">From</div>
          <div className="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
            <div className="accordion-body__contents">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sequi placeat distinctio dolor,
              amet magnam voluptatibus eos ex vero, sunt veritatis esse. Nostrum voluptatum et repudiandae vel sed,
              explicabo in?
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
          <div className="accordion-header js-accordion-header">Sub Panel 2</div>
          <div className="accordion-body js-accordion-body">
            <div className="accordion-body__contents">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sequi placeat distinctio dolor,
              amet magnam voluptatibus eos ex vero, sunt veritatis esse. Nostrum voluptatum et repudiandae vel sed,
              explicabo in?             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

);
```

JSON

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ervin Howell",
        "username": "Antonette",
        "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
        "address": {
            "street": "Victor Plains",
            "suite": "Suite 879",
            "city": "Wisokyburgh",
            "zipcode": "90566-7771",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-43.9509",
                "lng": "-34.4618"
            }
        },
        "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
        "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Clementine Bauch",
        "username": "Samantha",
        "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
        "address": {
            "street": "Douglas Extension",
            "suite": "Suite 847",
            "city": "McKenziehaven",
            "zipcode": "59590-4157",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-68.6102",
                "lng": "-47.0653"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
        "website": "ramiro.info",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
            "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
            "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
        "username": "Karianne",
        "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
        "address": {
            "street": "Hoeger Mall",
            "suite": "Apt. 692",
            "city": "South Elvis",
            "zipcode": "53919-4257",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "29.4572",
                "lng": "-164.2990"
            }
        },
        "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
        "website": "kale.biz",
        "company": {
            "name": "Robel-Corkery",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
            "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
        "username": "Kamren",
        "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
        "address": {
            "street": "Skiles Walks",
            "suite": "Suite 351",
            "city": "Roscoeview",
            "zipcode": "33263",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-31.8129",
                "lng": "62.5342"
            }
        },
        "phone": "(254)954-1289",
        "website": "demarco.info",
        "company": {
            "name": "Keebler LLC",
            "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
            "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
        "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
        "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
        "address": {
            "street": "Norberto Crossing",
            "suite": "Apt. 950",
            "city": "South Christy",
            "zipcode": "23505-1337",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-71.4197",
                "lng": "71.7478"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
        "website": "ola.org",
        "company": {
            "name": "Considine-Lockman",
            "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
            "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
        "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
        "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Rex Trail",
            "suite": "Suite 280",
            "city": "Howemouth",
            "zipcode": "58804-1099",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "24.8918",
                "lng": "21.8984"
            }
        },
        "phone": "210.067.6132",
        "website": "elvis.io",
        "company": {
            "name": "Johns Group",
            "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
            "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
        "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
        "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
        "address": {
            "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
            "suite": "Suite 729",
            "city": "Aliyaview",
            "zipcode": "45169",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-14.3990",
                "lng": "-120.7677"
            }
        },
        "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
        "website": "jacynthe.com",
        "company": {
            "name": "Abernathy Group",
            "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
            "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Glenna Reichert",
        "username": "Delphine",
        "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
        "address": {
            "street": "Dayna Park",
            "suite": "Suite 449",
            "city": "Bartholomebury",
            "zipcode": "76495-3109",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "24.6463",
                "lng": "-168.8889"
            }
        },
        "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
        "website": "conrad.com",
        "company": {
            "name": "Yost and Sons",
            "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
            "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
        "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
        "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
            "suite": "Suite 198",
            "city": "Lebsackbury",
            "zipcode": "31428-2261",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-38.2386",
                "lng": "57.2232"
            }
        },
        "phone": "024-648-3804",
        "website": "ambrose.net",
        "company": {
            "name": "Hoeger LLC",
            "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
            "bs": "target end-to-end models"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`user.address.street` is not type of `object`. It is type of `string`, so `JSON.stringify` method does not work here as you expect.

Just render only value of this key.

```
<div className="accordion-body__contents">
    {user.address.street}  
           <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
            Click me
           </a>
  </div>
```

### Update:

In case of address not exists you can check it before rendering like this:

```
{user.address ? users.address.street : 'N/A'}
```

Or use `lodash.get` method for in this case.
[Lodash get docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get)

Comment: @Arthem Mirchenko  I tried that first, did not  work   - error - Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

Comment: @Arthem Mirchenko, shows one row with 'N/A' then nothing

Comment: @ArunPrasadES because there is no data in address, try to console.log(user) and you will see.

Comment: @Arthem  All dataset has address in it, don't know what's happening

Comment: @Arun Prasad E S, you can `console.log(user)` in beginning of render method or `debug(user)` and you will se what is in there.